# Qt MVC Pattern and std::string

Tags: qt, model-view-controller, qabstractitemmodel

My question about model in Qt MVC pattern and std::string type.
For example, i have an object of struct generated from other library (boost, for example):

```
struct Foo{
   int age;
   std::string name;
}
```

And QAbstractListModel data implementation

```
QVariant FooListModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (index.row() < 0 || index.row() > fooList.count())
        return QVariant();
    const Foo & foo = contacts[fooList.row()];
    if (role == AgeRole)       //AgeRole = 0
        return foo.age;
    else if (role == NameRole) //NameRole = 1
        return QString::fromStdString(foo.name);
    return QVariant();
}
```

The problem is that name data doesn't work. Now i see only one solution - convert all Foo class objects to FooQt objects:

```
struct FooQt{
   int age;
   QString name;
}
```

Is there a more clean solution?

Comment: What does not work? Do you get a compiler error?

Comment: `foo.name()` -> `foo.name`

Comment: No, just no data displayed

Comment: So it's works fine only with FooQt objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your usage of Qt's View model. The roles describe differnet aspects of a single item, like displayed text, font, color, decoration, etc.

Your `AgeRole` (which is `0`)  equals `Qt::DisplayRole`. That's why the age seems to work. Your `NameRole` (which is `1`) equals `Qt::DecorationRole`. You would use that to specify an icon or background color.

You probably want to provide the data for different columns of your model:

```
QVariant FooListModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    // Only provide data for valid indices and display role
    if (index.row() < 0 || index.row() >= fooList.count() || role != Qt::DisplayRole)
        return QVariant();
    const Foo & foo = contacts[index.row()];
    // Check which column to display
    if (index.column() == AgeRole)       //AgeRole = 0
        return foo.age;
    else if (index.column() == NameRole) //NameRole = 1
        return QString::fromStdString(foo.name);
    return QVariant();
}
```